# GreenDroid actionbar ignoring menus?

Tags: greendroid

Can't Greendroid use menus defined in xml for displaying them in the actionbar?
For example the following menu is loaded in onCreateOptionsMenu(), but it doesnt appear in the actionbar.
I think ActionbarSherlock is able to do this, isn't greendroid capable too?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
   android:id="@+id/new_client"
   android:icon="@drawable/plus"
   android:showAsAction="always"
   android:title="new client"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

GreenDroid is a great library but if you are starting new project - choose ActionBarSherclock. Unfortunatelly GreenDroid isn't updated by its author anymore.

I'm using GreenDroid for one of my projects and I was looking for the same thing.

GreenDroid is an open source project. Maybe somebody will add this functionality to it in future. But probably this not simple thing to do.

I didn't check but I see that on GitHub there are now 228 forks of GreenDroid project. Maybe somebody actually add this functionality in one of them

https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/network

But like I said. If you are starting new project - ActionBarSherlock will be a better choice.